# Why isn't this working asp.net and javascript to validate pattern -

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate a field for not empty(spaces) and pattern matching
but the no spaces work but pattern matching causes error.

I've tried a few variations but it's not working. The field I'm trying to
validate is undefined.

```
<div visible="true" id="divTelephoneNumber" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-lg-6 nill">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTelephoneNumber" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtTelephoneNumber" Text="Telephone number *" CssClass="control-label" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelephoneNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="20" aria-label="Telephone number" ></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="required"></span>
        <asp:CustomValidator id="rfVTN" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTelephoneNumber"  ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Telephone Number is a required field. nnn-nnn-nnnn " ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTelephone"/> 
    </div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateTelephone(sender, args) {
        var rxP = RegExp("/^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/");
        if (rxP.IsMatch(txtTelephoneNumber.Text))
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need the `/` delimeters when using the RegExp constructor

Comment: what is an example for your phone number ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following validation rules.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
    ErrorMessage="Enter Email Address">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
    ErrorMessage="Please check the format of your email (ex. name@company.net)"
    ValidationExpression="^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```